# Throwing exception although right IP used

Tags: java, android, exception

```
package com.example.androidapp; 

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.Collection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nxp.jip.JIPImpl;
import com.nxp.jip.PacketHandlerIPv6;
import com.nxp.jip.exception.JipException;
import com.nxp.jip.service.JenNetIPNetwork;
import com.nxp.jip.service.Node;
import com.nxp.jip.service.Service;

public class Application extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_application);
TextView display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
PacketHandlerIPv6 my_packet = new PacketHandlerIPv6();
JIPImpl my_jip = new JIPImpl(my_packet);
Service service =new Service(my_jip); 
try{
    JenNetIPNetwork network = service.createNetwork(new          InetSocketAddress("fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff", 1873));
    display.setText("Connected :)");
}
catch(JipException e){
    display.setText("Not connected :(");
}

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.application, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

Although I am entering the right router IP it keeps throwing exception as if I am entering a wrong IP and the message "not connected" pops out 
And I am not connecting the router to the internet

The stack trace is:

```
com.nxp.jip.exception.JipException: Timeout
at com.nxp.jip.CommandHandler.execute(CommandHandler.java:125)
at com.nxp.jip.JIPImpl.get(JIPImpl.java:129)
at com.nxp.jip.service.Service.createNetwork(Service.java:272)
at com.example.androidapp.Application.onCreate(Application.java:32)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post the exception trace, include the _caused by_ section.

Comment: I don't get what is the exception trace ?

Comment: Maybe network on MainThread?

Comment: Did you check the `adb logcat` output?

Comment: No i didn't check it how can i do that ?

Comment: @insomniac can i have an example ?

Comment: You cannot use activities such as network in the Main thread, are you getting the NetworkOnMainThread Exception in the log?if yes i'll provide the answer

Comment: I don't know how to get it if u can give me little details i will tell u

Comment: Are you running this in Emulator of in device?

Comment: I am running it on bluestacks Emulator

Comment: ?????????????????????????/

Answer (score 0):

Print the stack trace from the exception you're passed. Are you sure the exception does not stem from the resolution of the `InetSocketAddress`? Try it again with various other hostnames, like "localhost" and perhaps an IPv4 equivalent address.

Comment: i tried ipv4 and i failed and should i put all the log cat generated ?

Comment: and i am using the same program on java and it is connecting normally

Comment: @insomniac Welcome to I couldn't comment until 20 minutes ago because my account is new. @OmarShagie3 It is throwing an exception, which may describe some part of your issue. It seems you haven't looked at what this exception actually says yet; instead of `display.setText("Not connected :(");` you should write `display.setText("Could not connect: " + e.getMessage());`. That should at least get you started.

Comment: it gives me a Timeout message

Comment: check the question again i edited it and put the printstacktrace output

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding Internet Permission in the manifest file, if not add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```