# Android connection to router

Tags: java, android, exception, timeout

I am developing an android application and it requests connecting to a linksys router and i wrote a code on java and it is working but when i tried to transform it to an android application i face a timeout exception in this line

```
JenNetIPNetwork network = service.createNetwork(new InetSocketAddress("fd04:bd3:80e8:2:215:8d00:32:54ff", 1873));
```

and i am using an emulator.
So is the problem that i am using an emulator not an android device?
And if there is other solutions any suggestions ?

Comment: is your network code is in same java class or you have created new thread for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Throwing exeption although right ip used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512296/throwing-exeption-although-right-ip-used)

Comment: @CrazyProggrammer no it is in the same class

Comment: @laalto no it is not a duplicate the question was not answered and i understood the problem that has nothing to do with the other question

Comment: As I read the questions, it's the same problem with the same code and therefore a duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers for help in case you don't get an answer.

Comment: here i am searching for a solution for the problem of not using a mobile phone and i just inserted one line to show the part i am connecting to the router nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is possibly 2 problems.

1) your immolator is not connected with router (its your computer.) so try to connect immolator to router or use real device.(this problem has major chance to generate this bug.)

&

2) All networking related stuff in android must be in other thread. try that out.

Try this hope your problem would be solve by this.

one more thing you have to add internet connectivity permission in xml.(if not then do as well)

Comment: i tried that solution is that what u mean by a new thread?
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // detect the view that was "clicked"
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            new LongOperation().execute("");
            break;
        }
    }

Comment: or you can create another class which extends Thread & connect network in run method.

Comment: can u give more details plz ?